# Trajectory of a person from plane to land

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

I had a very adventurous dream last night. I was jumping from an aeroplane to save myself from the bomb that was to explode in 2 minutes. Well it couldn't make it.

I am trying to get a small formula to predict the required acceleration one must reach to jump out opposite to the direction of the plane to land on a safe point on ground.

[image: Here is my diagram]

Here is the problem. A man/object needs to jump out opposite to the direction of a plane of horizontal velocity *v m/s*  whose altitude is *h m/s* with maximum internal straight path inside it is *x m* (as the person/object initial velocity is *0 m/s* at the left extreme of the path). He has to land *d m* from the vertical point on the ground from where he jumps.

[image: That would look something like this]

What should be his acceleration and the velocity at the tip of the plane from where he jumps?

I know how trajectory works but don't know for an object that is not rest at some point vertically from the ground.

Comment: Are you neglecting wind resistance(drag) ?

Comment: No, I am not neglecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:  Your skydiver is never going to make it.**

Suppose the skydiver runs backwards *at the airspeed of the plane* and jumps.  When he leaves the plane, he will have zero forward velocity, and will therefore drop straight down to the ground from the point at which he jumped.  But the drop zone is behind the plane in your diagram, which implies that the skydiver must be traveling with a backwards velocity relative to the ground to make it there, which means that he must have been moving *even faster than the airspeed of the plane* when he jumped.

Given that typical airspeeds for skydiving planes are in the range of 70–80 knots (over 120 km/h), and the world's fastest sprinter can only run the 100 meters at a speed of less than 40 km/h, the stunt as described is impossible.

If you're allowing your skydiver to be fired out of a cannon or some such, the problem could in principle be solved.  However, as air resistance on a human-sized object is not negligible, the problem becomes quite hard.  In particular, in the presence of air resistance, there is no simple equation that will tell you what the skydiver's horizontal velocity must be to land in the landing zone.

Rather, what one would have to do would be to solve a set of differential equations for the skydiver's $x$ and $y$ position as a function of time, given an initial position and velocity.  These differential equations would also depend on the skydiver's mass and attitude while falling, as these affect the ratio of weight to drag forces.  One could then plot the landing point as a function of initial velocity and read the "correct" initial velocity off of this graph.  One could even do some empirical curve-fitting to find a simple-ish equation that gave you the required initial velocity to a good approximation. However, to the best of my knowledge, it is not be possible to find an equation that gives you the exact required initial velocity as a function of distance to the landing zone.

Comment: I agree the diagram is misleading at best. He would have to jump from the plane before he was overhead(or past) the landing zone as he will be falling to the left in the diagram.

Comment: "even faster than the airspeed of the plane","world's fastest sprinter can only run the 100 meters at a speed of less than 40 km/h, the stunt as described is impossible". It's the correct interpretation but  couldn't it be an object of irregular shape or maybe a superhuman hypothetically?

Comment: @user57304:  Edited to add how one would actually try to solve this problem.